# Min-Width Max-Width in Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013 for responsive eBlast

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I am making an eBlast for a client  [(it can be found here)](http://lonebeacondevelopment.com/IR_Heafner.html)

Everything looks good except the bottom picture of of the gentleman, in Outlook it gets blown up to an enormous size.

I am running into issues in certain Outlook email services. The eBlast passed all Litmus test but Outlook 2010 and 2013, when I further researched the issue I found it was because Max-width and min-width just does not matter in Outlook as it does not read that code.

Can anyone please take a look at this code and suggest some fixes that I could apply to the image at the bottom of the eblast, it currently sits in this code block:

```html
<table style="border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;vertical-align: top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
<tbody><tr style="vertical-align: top">
    <td style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top;width: 100%;padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px" align="center">
        <div style="font-size:12px" align="center">
        <img class="center" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block;border: none;height: auto;line-height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;float: none;max-width: 146px" align="center" border="0" src="http://www.lonebeacondevelopment.com/images/jfir.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image" style="max-width:146px !important; width:50%">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would be forever grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be setting a max-width either way why not go ahead and set the size of the image to be that or set it to be a pre-determined width from the get-go.

That way your fallback is that it loads the image at its largest since Outlook is going to ignore that max-width either way and display the full image.

Since you're not going to be going higher than 600px there really shouldn't be any issues with either hard-coding it or just adjusting the actual full size image instead of trying to adjust the size using css.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you've got two style attributes in the same element. One of them is going to be ignored. For Outlook, the best solution I've found is to add an old fashioned explicit width="146" before the style where you set a max-width. Outlook will only pay attention the old attribute, while more modern clients will interpret the max-width in the style.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, Outlook does not support `min-width` or `max-width`.

Since Outlook 2010 and 2013 are desktop-only and use Microsoft office to render email, we can use [ghost tables](http://labs.actionrocket.co/make_mobile_email_work_in_outlook) and [VML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) to make the image display only at 146 pixels wide in these email clients.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<div style="max-width: 146px;">
    <!--[if mso]>
    /* Everything inside here is only read by Outlook 07/10/13 */
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="146" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <![endif]-->
        <img class="center" src="http://www.lonebeacondevelopment.com/images/jfir.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image" style="width: 100%;">
    <!--[if mso]>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
```